# Call a method on the value of a data key?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, key-value, vuetify.js

I have been working on a game and I need to call a function on the value of the key 'sides' (similar to 'onclick="rollDice(6)"'). I've tried using mustache interpolation and also v-binding, but I cannot seem to return anything other than NaN or undefined.

Relevant markup:

```
   <v-list>
    <v-list-tile v-for="die in dice" :key="die.name">
      <v-list-tile-avatar>
        <v-avatar size="32px" tile @click="rollDice()" >
          <img :src="die.img">
        </v-avatar>
      </v-list-tile-avatar>
      <v-list-tile-title>{{ die.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
```

From data:

```
dice: [
    { img: require("../assets/d4.svg"), name: "d4", sides: 4 },
    { img: require("../assets/d6.svg"), name: "d6", sides: 6  },
    { img: require("../assets/d8.svg"), name: "d8", sides: 8 },
  ]
```

From methods:

```
  rollDice: function(sides){
  var rollResult = Math.ceil(Math.random() * sides)
  console.log(rollResult)
}
```

I tried to keep the linked code minimal, but if I can link anything further, I'd be glad to. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `die.sides` to the click handler like this: `@click="rollDice(die.sides)"`.

Full code will be:

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-tile v-for="die in dice" :key="die.name">
    <v-list-tile-avatar>
      <v-avatar size="32px" tile @click="rollDice(die.sides)" >
        <img :src="die.img">
      </v-avatar>
    </v-list-tile-avatar>
    <v-list-tile-title>{{ die.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
  </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, my issue was a simple one. I made the following change and it seems to be working as expected after making the following changes to the click event:

```
<v-avatar size="32px" tile @click="rollDice(die.sides)">
```

If there is a better way this can be done, I'd be interested to see. I am new to Vue, but having a blast with it, but I could definitely stand to learn some best practices!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <v-list>
<v-list-tile v-for="(die, index) in dice" :key="die.name">
  <v-list-tile-avatar>
    <v-avatar size="32px" tile @click="rollDice(die.sides)" >
      <img :src="die.img">
    </v-avatar>
  </v-list-tile-avatar>
  <v-list-tile-title>{{ die.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
</v-list-tile>
```

Comment: I realized my mistake shortly after posting this, embarrassingly enough. Out of curiosity, is there an advantage to using `v-for="(die, index) in dice" :key="die.name"` over `v-for="die in dice" :key="die.name"`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: when you use for each makes use key is needed to be unique instead of a string you can get index as key and assign in to :key="index" that is standard way https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-with-simple-arrays-what-key-to-use/13692/3

Comment: Excellent! I will be sure to do it this way in the future! Thanks again!